# Can't Access Class Variable From WebSocket Server

Tags: python, variables, websocket

So I am trying to get the amount from progressive in the Progressive class. However, I have tried so many times to access it from the WebSocket class, but can't. What's wrong here?

Thanks!

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import WebSocket, SimpleWebSocketServer

class Progressive():
    def __init__(self):
        self.progressive = 0

    def affect(self, amt):
        self.progressive += amt


class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):
    progressive = Progressive()

    def handleMessage(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        # echo message back to client
        self.sendMessage(str(self.data))

        print 'Sent back', str(self.data)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'
        print progressive.progressive

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, SimpleEcho)
server.serveforever()
```

Comment: What result are you seeing?

Comment: @bwbrowning It never prints when a client connects, but the self.address, connected prints fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `progressive` in the class scope, but trying to refer to it as if it's defined in local scope. You need to prefix it with `self` or `SimpleEcho`.

```
class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):
    progressive = Progressive()

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'
        print self.progressive.progressive
```

Same issue with your `Progressive` class. Note that `affect` should be defined with an initial `self` argument, as it's not a `staticmethod`:

```
class Progressive():
    progressive = 0

    def affect(self, amt):
        self.progressive += amt
```

**HOWEVER!**

What you're doing here means that *every* instance of `Progressive` will modify the *same* `progressive` attribute (and ditto every `SimpleEcho` instance). What you probably want to do is declare the `progressive` attribute on both classes when an instance is initialised:

```
class Progressive():
    def __init__(self):
        self.progressive = 0
```

Comment: I tried the self's multiple times and knew they were right, but figured maybe not. It turns out the self.progressive.progressive did the trick. Thanks Matthew!